# Map objects with EF

Tags: entity-framework, model, ef-code-first, mapping

I am having some issues regarding mapping the object with EF Code first.

I have three classes:

-Employee
-AssesmentOnEmployee
-Assesment

Employee has a one-to-many relationship with AssesmentOnEmployee
AssesmentOnEmployee has a one-to-one relationship with Assement.

Code:

```
public class AssesmentOnEmployee
{
    public int AssesmentOnEmployeeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Assesment Assesments { get; set; }

    public virtual int AssesmentUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee AssesmentUser { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssesmentOnEmployee> AssesmentOnEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

AppContext.cs:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssesmentOnEmployee>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Assesments)
            .WithRequiredDependent(t => t.AssesmentOnEmployee);


modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(t => t.AssesmentOnEmployees)
            .WithRequired(t => t.AssesmentUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.AssesmentUserId);
```

When I try to add-migration and update database I get this error:

> The object 'PK_dbo.AssesmentOnEmployee' is dependent on column 'AssesmentOnEmployeeId'.
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN AssesmentOnEmployeeId failed because one or more objects access this column.

Is there anyone who can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of things. It seems that `AssesmentOnEmployee` table already exists, and you are trying to alter it, but it is violating an PK constraint.

The easiest way to solve it, is deleting the existing table and generating the migration again, using `add-migration YourLastMigrationName -force`.

If this does not solve your problem, leave a comment below, then we can try a different approach.

Comment: It did not notwork, I can't figure out where I went wrong.
I still get this message after running my 
add-migration MyLastMigrationName -force
Update-Database

The object 'PK_dbo.AssesmentOnEmployee' is dependent on column 'AssesmentOnEmployeeId'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN AssesmentOnEmployeeId failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: show the code generated at the migration script file